# Changing up gamma with -lavfi and ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

This is my first time posting on this forum, so don't be too rough on me, haha.

I have recently started taking up FFmpeg as a side project for my media class, and I am facing some problems when it comes to changing up some aspects of gamma/contrast.

Whenever I use a command like this:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -lavfi colorcontrast=gm=-1:gmw=1 -y -c:a copy output.mp4`

the problem I have is of playing the specific output video (the video is only available when it is played by QuickTime Player, yet when I try to open it on other video players or video editing programs a message appears that the video is unavailable).

I have already been using other FFmpeg commands for cropping, removing audio track etc., however this is my first time trying and/or having a problem of this kind for more complex changes of video track.

Thank you and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

The following video codec settings should be the most common for all devices

```
-c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p
```

H.264 baseline profile and level 3.0 settings require less resources.